# Where can I find information on setting up ASP.NET web applications with MySQL?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I am interested in developing web applications in ASP.NET using MySQL, is this something difficult to do/does it easily integrate with Visual Studio 2010? I really like using the .NET platform for web applications but I would prefer to use MySQL over Microsoft SQL Server. Can somebody shed some light/direct me to good links?

Sorry if this is a ridiculous question, I'm new to web applications and the .NET framework.

Comment: Where can you find information about setting up an ASP.NET web application with MySql?  Seriously?  Have you tried *Google*? :)

Comment: It's not much different than any other database. Just use a different data provider.

Answer (score 4):

Try some of these links to start

[Using MySQL with ASP.NET](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/09/using-mysql-with-asp-net-2/)

[Connect to MySQL database from ASP.NET](http://www.sqlstrings.com/mysql-asp.net-connection.htm)

[Using MySQL with ASP.NET](http://www.christianasp.net/usingmysql50withaspnet-part1.aspx)

**EDIT** : Looks like you will have to use an ODBC connection. You'll need to [set up an ODBC connection on your PC](http://www.hbp.usm.my/feedback/itTips/TipsCreateODBCDataSource.htm) and wherever you deploy the app. This is an example that I've used when connecting to an [Informix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Informix) database, which used an ODBC connection. You'll need to [install the drivers for MySql first](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

Web.config connection string for an Informix database

```
<add name="odbcConnection" connectionString="Driver={IBM INFORMIX 3.82 32 BIT};uid=odbcUsername;pwd=odbcPassword;database=odbcDatabase; host=odbcHostName;srvr=odbcServerName;serv=odbcServ;pro=onsoctcp;cloc=en_US.819;dloc=en_US.819;vmb=0;condb=1;xcl=0;curb=0;scur=0;icur=0;oac=1;optofc=0;rkc=0;odtyp=0;fbs=4096;ddfp=0;dnl=0;rcwc=0" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
```

DataAccess method

```
Dim cnStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("odbcConnection").ToString

Public Function GetTable() As Data.DataSet
    Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
    Dim sql As String = ""

        Using myConnection As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(cnStr)
            Dim myCommand As New OdbcCommand()
            Dim oda As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter()
                sql = "SELECT * FROM table"

                If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    myConnection.Open()
                    myCommand = New OdbcCommand(sql, myConnection)
                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    oda.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    oda.Fill(ds, "tblInfo")
                End If
        End Using
    Return ds
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add `Mysql.Data` Nuget Package to your project and then just change the connection string for mysql server and it will work for you.